# Adding cx_Freeze msi to path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, cx-freeze

I have an msi and when installed I want it to add the `exe` to path.

I have found this:

> add_to_path    add the target directory to the PATH environment variable; the default value is True if there are any console based executables and False otherwise

From [the documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#bdist-msi).

I have tried adding this to the setup script:

```
setup(  name = "cabbage",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "just a vegetable",
        add_to_path = True, # <-- Just here
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("spam.py", base=base)])
```

This returns:

> UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'add_to_path'

I also tried from the command line:

```
C:\Users\Simon\Desktop>python setup.py bdist_msi add_to_path=True
invalid command name 'add_to_path=True'
```

How do I add this option?

Comment: What are your Python version, cx_freeze version, and your PATH variable?

Comment: @Bachrc x32 bit Python 3.7.0 and cx_Freeze 5.1.1

Comment: Also I am confused by PATH variable, what do you mean exactly?  The path to the exe I package in the msi?  If so `C:\TestProgram\bin` @Bachrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines in your setup.py script to make it work.

```
  if 'bdist_msi' in sys.argv:

        sys.argv += ['--add-to-path', 'True']
```

Your code should look like:

```
 if 'bdist_msi' in sys.argv:

        sys.argv += ['--add-to-path', 'True']


 setup(  name = "cabbage",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "just a vegetable",
    add_to_path = True, # <-- Just here
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("spam.py", base=base)])
```

Run command: python setup.py bdist_msi